# Trying to check for 3 of a kind with arrays (Yahtzee) C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to check for if the kept dice rolls (which can be up to 5) are 3 of a kind or not, so I'm trying to compare the dice roll values to each other.

The first value of R is showing as 0 of course, but the second value of R after the code is run is showing as 8191 every time, and I'm not entirely sure why.

I've also tried using 
r++ instead of r += r+1, but of course that didn't change anything.

```
int r = 0;
          cout << "first value of R is " << r << endl;
          for(int t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
            for(int w = 0; w < 5; w++) {
              if(keptDice[t] == keptDice[w] ) {
                r += r + 1;
              }
            }
          }
          cout << "Value of R is " << r << endl;
```

Comment: `r += r + 1` is equivalent to `r = r + r + 1`.
So every t loop, it is guaranteed that some w == t.

Comment: `r += r + 1` should be either `r += 1`, `r = r + 1`, or `++r`. But the loops are also wrong, since `t` and `w` will often be equal, and `keptDice[i] == keptDice[w]` will be trivially (and pointlessly) true.

Comment: [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3750e02cbc4e059c) doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

```
r += r + 1
```

is the same as writing

```
r = r + r + 1
```

r is doubling every time.  Interestingly, it's always 1 less than 2^n

```
r = 0 + 0 + 1 (1)
r = 1 + 1 + 1 (3)
r = 3 + 3 + 1 (7)
r = 7 + 7 + 1 (15)
r = 15 + 15 + 1 (31)
r = 31 + 31 + 1 (63)
r = 63 + 63 + 1 (127)
r = 127 + 127 + 1 (255)
r = 255 + 255 + 1 (511)
r = 511 + 511 + 1 (1023)
r = 1023 + 1023 + 1 (2047)
r = 2047 + 2047 + 1 (4095)
r = 4095 + 4095 + 1 (8191)
```

Your program is counting 13 matches.  For yahtzee, you probably want an array that counts matches, otherwise you're doubling up on each die.  For example, if you had

```
1 2 3 4 1
```

It would count the first 1 matching the last die AND the last die matching the first (2 matches).

What would be more sensible is to count how many 1's you have, how many 2s you have, and store in an array

```
int diceCount[6];
for(int num = 1; num <= 6; num++) {
        for(int w = 0; w < 5; w++) {
          int count = 0;
          if(keptDice[w] == num ) {
            count++;
          }
          diceCount[num-1] = count;
        }
```

This way when it's done, if you had two 1's, then diceCount[0] will be 2

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: The modified code you supplied though was a tad bit incorrect. You have to put int count outside of the for loop, or else it won't work correctly. Once you do that it works fine

Answer (score 1):

The point is that in the second for loop yo have tor start from t (int w = t;...) otherwise you would compare each dice with itself which will be naturally equal. Plus use r++ instead of r += r + 1 which is definitely wrong but I think that is just a misspelling.

```
int r = 0;
cout << "first value of R is " << r << endl;
for(int t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
    for(int w = t; w < 5; w++) {
        if(keptDice[t] == keptDice[w] ) {
            r++;
        }
    }
}
cout << "Value of R is " << r << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your approach, but generalized to N-of-a-kind:

```
int N = 3; // N in [1;5]
bool isNOfAKind = false;
for(int t = 0; t < 6-N; t++) { // skip searches with less elements than N
    int r = 0; // r must be reset for each count
    for(int w = t+1; w < 5; w++) { // avoid comparing to self
        if(keptDice[t] == keptDice[w]) {
            r++;
        }
    }
    // found a solution already? then bail out.
    if(r == N) {
        isNOfAKind = true;
        break;
    }
}
cout << N << " of a kind? " << isNOfAKind << endl;
```